# Using the syntax IF THEN ELSE, to calculate Tax charge

Tags: microsoft-excel

1) If the total amount to be subjected to tax is 30,000.00
2) The first 2,200.00 to 3,000.00 is taxed at 25%.
3) The second 3,000.01 to 5,900.00 is taxed at 30%
4) The remaining amount is taxed at 35%

Help me calculate tax using the IF THEN ELSE syntax in a macro in excel.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this with IF THEN ELSE in a macro (sounds like a homework problem).  You could accomplish the result with VLOOKUP and a simple table (no macro and a single, short function).

Answer (score 0):

It took me 10 seconds to Google: excel tax rate formula

[Tiered Tax Rates in Excel](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/taxes-5-excel-formulas-must-know/)

```
=IF(AND(A2 >= 0, A2 < 2200), 0%, 
IF(AND(A2 >= 2200, A2 <= 3000), 25%, 
IF(AND(A2 >= 3000.01,  A2 <= 5900 ), 30%, 
IF(AND(A2 >= 5901, A2 < 99999), 35%, 
"double check"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the macro code for this.

Function MyTax(Value As Currency) As Currency

'Setup variables

Dim TAX As Currency

' this will hold the calculated tax through the steps of the function

Dim Amount As Currency

' this holds how much is being resolved

Amount = Value

'setup constants

Const loRange As Currency = 2200#

Const MidRange As Currency = 3000#

Const TopRange As Currency = 5900#

Const BottomTier As Double = 0#

Const LoTier As Double = 0.25

Const Midtier As Double = 0.3

Const UpperTier As Double = 0.35

' the example was not clear on how the values are set. the above reflects

' the first 2200 is not taxed, between 2200 and 3000 is taxed at .25,

' between 3000 and 5900 is taxed at 30%, and anything higher is taxed at 35%

TAX = 0

' first tier is the upper tier

If Amount > TopRange Then

```
' will need to pay the highest tax and also reduce amount

TAX = (Amount - TopRange) * UpperTier

Amount = TopRange
```

End If

' same general approach for remaining tiers

If Amount > MidRange Then

```
TAX = TAX + ((Amount - MidRange) * Midtier)

Amount = MidRange
```

End If

' repeat for low range

If Amount > loRange Then

TAX = TAX + ((Amount - loRange) * LoTier)

' we are done so no need to adjust amount

End If

' just need to return amount of tax

MyTax = TAX

End Function